# Folium map in Django only says 'None'

Tags: python, django, mapping, folium

I am trying to create map in Django using folium. There is no error message, but instead of the map it displays the word 'None'.

I have a django web app that reads from a postgressql database and displays the records. That is working. I want to add a map with markers, and the markers will get coordinates from the postgresql data. When I try to create a map using iframe, I get the word 'None'. I have tried just hard coding a starting location to just create the map. I still get the word 'None'.

I also typed the hard coded coordinates into google maps, and made a flask app that creates the map. They show up fine.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import PhotoInfo
import folium
import pandas

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    VarPhotoInfo = PhotoInfo.objects.order_by('DateTaken')

    context = {'PhotoInfo': VarPhotoInfo }

    return render(request,'natureapp/index.html',context)

def show_map(request):
    #creation of map comes here + business logic
    #PhotoInfo1 = PhotoInfo.objects.order_by('DateTaken')
    map = folium.Map(location=[33.57137166666667, -117.76325])

    map.save("natureapp/map.html")
    context = {'my_map': map }

    return render(request, 'natureapp/map.html', context)
```

map.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NatureMapper</title>
      </head>
<h1>Map goes here </h1>

   {{ my_map.render }}

</html>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NatureMapper</title>
      </head>
<h1>Here it is! </h1>
 {% if PhotoInfo %}
  {% for Photo in PhotoInfo %}
 <p>there is info.</p>
   <p> {{ Photo.PhotoName }}</p>
   <p> {{ Photo.Lat }}</p>
   <p> {{ Photo.Long }}</p>
   <p>  <img src="{{ Photo.PhotoImage.url }}" width = "240" alt=""></p>
  {% endfor %}
 {% else %}
 <p>there is no info.</p>
 {% endif %}
 <iframe id="encoder_iframe" height=95% width="90%" src="{% url 'show_map' %}">
     </iframe>
</html>
```

There is no error message. Just the word 'None'

Comment: Have you tried running `map = folium.Map(location=[33.57137166666667, -117.76325])` in a regular python shell and inspecting the returned `map` object, and `map.render`?

Comment: Yes, I can create the map in a regular python script. I'm able to create it in a Flask app,